# Is a permutation test valid in comparing a fraud block policy false positive rate across two different months?

Tags: experiment-design, bootstrap, permutation-test, fraud-detection

I'm looking to conduct a counterfactual experiment in an e-commerce fraud context. When a fraud policy blocks a transaction you necessarily will never know if it was truly fraudulent. I'm trying to sample this blocked population with two goals in mind:

1. Get a reasonable estimate of the false positive rate (ie. how many transactions that were blocked were actually fraudulent or not)
2. Compare this false positive measurement across points in time (monthly etc.) and determine if we are seeing statistically significant changes in the performance of our policy

I'm looking to target a minimum sample size that will help me achieve these goals and I've arrived at the following methodology:

1. **Estimate**: First I looked at the wilson score interval for a binomial proportion but I don't believe its assumptions hold for my population in question. So I've landed on bootstrapping confidence intervals as I believe this is more flexible and applicable to a population for which I have a lack of understanding on the true distribution. I'm targeting a 10% confidence with on either side which I get from about 80 samples with an assumption of 30% false positive rate.
2. **Comparison**: I'm proposing to test the hypothesis between subsequent months that the fpr has increased or decreased by some effect size. For similar reasons as the choice of bootstrap I'm proposing a permutation test for this setup. Here I'm less sure if my experiment design is valid. My thinking being that I am treating each month as its own sample and testing that the mean (false positive rate) has increased or not by some effect size. I've run some simulations and I can see that if I simulate the population for two months with a different true mean, I can get vastly different results for my permutation test when the sample is in the range of 100. Is this just the best I can hope to do with that small of a sample size, and is it even worth doing if I don't trust that my sample size will give me useful results? I'm also a bit worried about the assumption of exchangeability in the permutation test for my population, where one transaction is fraud or not should have no bearing on the other if we're assuming that I'm comparing distinct users transacting. Maybe it's approximately correct, is that a valid assumption to make?

Is there another way of thinking about this comparison over time problem that I'm missing here or am I just inherently going to be limited by the fact that I'm trying to minimize sample size as much as possible?

Comment: "*When a fraud policy blocks a transaction you necessarily will never know if it was truly fraudulent*" - well, when you block a legitimate transaction, typically the customer will call and say so. The problem is that valuable information is often dealt with in a call center -- sadly it seems to have little impact on the settings of fraud policy, which seems to result from a systemic communication problem.